# Создание таблицы Qt (цикл?)

Tags: sql, qt, qtcreator

Есть ли возможность создать программу для создания  таблиц Sql в Qt Creator?
Проще говоря, как сделать так, чтобы в моем проекте пользователь мог сам добавлять таблицы? 
Например, в lineEdit вводить число строк и столбцов, названия стрлбцов и из ComboBox выбирать тип. Я знаю, как получить оттуда значения, но не представляю, как прописать CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS так, чтобы не зависело от количества столбцов. (Не писать же тысячу этих приказов для каждого случая...)
В Qt я почти дерево, так что хотелось бы и саму форму, как пишется, и пояснения к ней на будущее. :D

Comment: Если писать на "голом" Qt то, да, надо повозиться. Почитайте документацию про раздел QtSql. А далее, если надо будет серьезно работать с БД, то я рекомендую плотненько изучить вот эту библиотеку https://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt/doc/tutorial/dbo.html#_a_first_session

Comment: Не думаю, что серьезно, просто дать возмодность пользователю создавать свою таблицу...

Comment: Читайте раздел QtSql

Comment: @Elina можете формировать строку обычной склейкой QString. Либо создать пустую таблицу, а потом с помощью ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN добавлять столбцы в цикле.

Comment: @amiranys Да, я уже сама так и поступила в момент создания программы (мы её сдали ещё 4 декабря), но спасибо большое за ответ!

Comment: @Elina рад за вас